# Angular 5 trigger event from code with ViewChild

Tags: angular, angular5, viewchild

Is it possible in Angular to trigger the change event defined in the HTML via a method in typescript?

I'm grabbing my selector via a ViewChild.

```js
@ViewChild('org3') org3Selector: HTMLSelectElement;
```

and that element has a `change` event set:

```
<select class="form-control" id="orgLevel3" name="orgLevel3" #org3
        (change)="onOrg3Change($event.target.value, org4, org5)">
    <option>-- Select --</option>
    <option *ngFor="let name of validOrgLevel3" value="{{name.id}}">
        {{name.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

where `org4` and `org5` are just two other select elements.

If I want that method to be called based on something I did via code (like manually change the value that the selection would have) Should I be "triggering" that event somehow, or should my code just manually call the `onOrg3Change` method since I've got the references to the select elemetn?

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually trigger the event once the value gets changed. Angular does not know if the value of any html element value gets changed from the code (which means not by interaction)

You can emit the event in the following way :

```
@ViewChild('org3') org3: ElementRef;

this.org3.nativeElement.value = 'two';
this.org3.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

See this simple [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cydj5o)

Comment: I see your example works, but when I set my value it's not actually changing the dropdown at all :(

Comment: I'm setting it to an `id` that's definitely in the `validOrgLevel3` array.  I'm not getting any errors in the console, but the selector just doesn't change.

Comment: It does change, I have updated the demo link with your exact same code. Check the demo once again.